# smtp_default connection is not working in AWS Airflow service

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I am using AWS Airflow 2.2.2 version in our project.

I am using SMTP for sending emails for which I have ben using environment variables as follows -

[image: SMTP env variables]

Due to following deprecation warning in the logs, I moved these SMTP connection details to AWS connections named *smtp_default* (as per the documentation) and deleted SMTP details from environment variables, expecting the SMTP details will be taken from AWS Airflow connections and warning will disappear.

> WARNING -
> /usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py:102
> PendingDeprecationWarning: Fetching SMTP credentials from
> configuration variables will be deprecated in a future release. Please
> set credentials using a connection instead.

However, now, I am getting following messages in logs -

> [2023-09-15, 17:23:47 UTC] {{base.py:79}} INFO - Using connection to:
> id: smtp_default. Host: some_host, Port: 25, Schema: , Login: some_login,
> Password: None, extra: {'from_email': 'some_email'}
>
> [2023-09-15, 17:23:47 UTC] {{logging_mixin.py:109}} WARNING -
> /usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py:102
> PendingDeprecationWarning: Fetching SMTP credentials from
> configuration variables will be deprecated in a future release. Please
> set credentials using a connection instead.
>
> [2023-09-15, 17:23:47 UTC] {{configuration.py:381}} WARNING -
> section/key [smtp/smtp_user] not found in config

This means in spite of providing  smtp_default connection, it tries to read the details from environment variables.

Am I missing out on anything?
Do I need to make anything else to make sure that DAG code is reading details from smtp_default?